# unity 2D: simple enemy shooting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D game. If I wanted a simple enemy canon shooting side to side every 5 seconds, how would I go about it ?

I know that I would need to add a colider and rigidbody but not quite sure how to approach this, since am still grasping the whole idea

[Red = Enemy/ Rough idea/Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prmqy.png)

Thank you

Comment: [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) you can find Unity tutorials. You will learn how to **instantiate** an object and **addforce** to it. You will also learn about the collision callbacks. Please don't ask more questions without adding code in your question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to create a type of gameobject to be used as a 'bullet'. This gameobject when spawned has a script on it to make it travel in a certain direction.

You can move them using force (physics) or you can translate them from one place to another which is to move them 'absolutely' and ignore physics in the environment.

Then you can use a collider on this object to detect when it hits the player using either the OnCollisionEnter method or the OnTriggerEnter method.

There are some tutorials on it here so I hope they help.
[Creating](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/creating-shots?playlist=17147)  [Shooting](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/shooting-shots?playlist=17147)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to think how your enemy should behavior, Just walk side by side or find the enemy as Navmesh.

I found this scritpt on unity website:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;     // The time in seconds between each attack.
    public int attackDamage = 10;               // The amount of health taken away per attack.

```
Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator component.
GameObject player;                          // Reference to the player GameObject.
PlayerHealth playerHealth;                  // Reference to the player's health.
EnemyHealth enemyHealth;                    // Reference to this enemy's health.
bool playerInRange;                         // Whether player is within the trigger collider and can be attacked.
float timer;                                // Timer for counting up to the next attack.


void Awake ()
{

    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
    enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
    anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
}
```

//OntriggerEnter and On triggerExit the enemy will follow enemy everytime the player enter on collide and stop if player exit
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
    {
        // If the entering collider is the player...
        if(other.gameObject == player)
        {
            // ... the player is in range.
            playerInRange = true;
        }
    }

```
void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
{
    // If the exiting collider is the player...
    if(other.gameObject == player)
    {
        // ... the player is no longer in range.
        playerInRange = false;
    }
}


void Update ()
{
    // Add the time since Update was last called to the timer.
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    // If the timer exceeds the time between attacks, the player is in range and this enemy is alive...
    if(timer >= timeBetweenAttacks && playerInRange && enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0)
    {
        // ... attack.
        Attack ();
    }

    // If the player has zero or less health...
    if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        // ... tell the animator the player is dead.
        anim.SetTrigger ("PlayerDead");
    }
}


void Attack ()
{
    // Reset the timer.
    timer = 0f;

    // If the player has health to lose...
    if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
    {
        // ... damage the player.
        playerHealth.TakeDamage (attackDamage);
    }
}
```

}